# Should I evaluate a range?

Tags: bash

*Re-asking this here, since it doesn't belong in the Code Review SE.*

I was always taught to never have static expressions in code, as it is an unnecessary operation that will always have the same output. For example, you would never have `if 6 < 7` (aside from people slapping the occasional `while true` around).

That being said, I have a functioning bash script as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in {0..9}
do
    ...some stuff...
done
```

However, PyCharm is giving my hell for this re-iterating my concern in my first paragraph. It's counter suggestion is to have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
for i in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
do
    ...some stuff...
done
```

The logic is that it will not have to evaluate the range itself, thus increasing speed.

## My Question

I think that the range looks nicer and, as far as I know, it won't actually affect speed (I don't mean noticeably, I mean at all), as it is simply iterating as it goes. Am I incorrect in thinking so?

It's a peeve of mine to waste cycles, but it's a greater peeve of mine to write grotesque looking code.

Comment: `for ((i=0; i<=9; i++))` is really the better form. `{0..9}` can't be used with variables, and it's expanded as a whole before the loop even starts.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Why is that? Is it because it doesn't need to store the entire array so it will only consume one integer worth of memory at a time?

Comment: Exactly right -- `{0..9}` is expanded into a list before iteration starts, `for ((i=0; i<=9; i++))` has only one value of `i` in memory at a time.

Comment: That said, the bigger problem is readability. If I see `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`, it's a lot of trouble to make sure that it really *is* the sequence we want and not a subtle typo like `0 1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9` or `0 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9`. By contrast, an expression that describes the range is succinct and *can't be anything but what it looks like*.

Comment: Gotcha. I don't know why I didn't think of doing that for bash when I've done that in other coding languages. If you want to post that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Comment: Never say never; I'd rather see something like `t=$(( 8 * 3600 ))` than `t=28800`.

Comment: @chepner But that's an extra calculation your system now has to do every time that code is run,, as opposed to it not having to evaluate the expression. Why not have `t=28800 # Seconds in 8 hours` so if someone needs to change it to 9 hours later, they can just recalculate it once, change the variable, so the system doesn't have to calculate it every time it is run?

Comment: The cost of a single multiplication is dwarfed by the cost of starting a new process, which is one of the more common tasks of a shell script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice approach in bash or other shells adopting ksh extensions is a C-style `for` loop:

```
for ((i=0; i<=9; i++)); do
  echo "Doing some stuff with $i"
done
```

This has advantages over the `{0..9}` syntax in that it works with variables (`{$min..$max}` doesn't work, because brace expansions happens before variable expansions do) and avoids needing to store the full list in memory at once, and it has advantages over `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` because the latter is hard to check for typos (it's trickier to visually spot the problems with `0 1 2 3 5 4 6 7 8 9` or `0 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9`).